# Supervisor постоянно перезапускает php-скрипт

Tags: linux, laravel, supervisor

У меня есть проект на laravel. Следующая команда

```
php artisan websocket:serve
```

запускает сервер веб-сокетов на порту 6001. Чтобы постоянно не запускать сокеты руками, я настроил supervisor со следующим конфигом:

```
[program:laravel-socket]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/messanger/artisan websocket:serve
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/messanger/storage/logs/supervisor_queue-work.log
```

Сокеты успешно работают, однако логи постоянно забиваются ошибкой, что сокеты уже запущены. Мне кажется, что supervisor постоянно перезапускает эту команду. Как сделать так, чтоб он один раз ее запустил? ОС Ubuntu

Comment: Расскажите кто-нибудь мне недалёкому, зачем все с кем я общался так любят этот супервизор? Чем не устраивает системд? Я понимаю тех, кто за sysV топит, но тут-то зачем?

Comment: В документации по Laravel рекомендуется supervisor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось все просто, нужно было из конфига удалить строчку

```
numprocs=2
```